# gdb compile issue yyin and lexer_init

Tags: makefile, compilation, gdb, bison

I am trying to compile gdb 9.2 in Ubuntu 18.04, The following errors are printed.

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ata/gdb-9.2/build/gdb'
  CXX    ada-exp.o
ada-exp.y: In function ‘int ada_parse(parser_state*)’:
ada-exp.y:736:15: error: ‘yyin’ was not declared in this scope
ada-exp.y:736:15: note: suggested alternative: ‘yylen’
ada-exp.y:736:3: error: ‘lexer_init’ was not declared in this scope
ada-exp.y:736:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘pex_init’
In file included from ada-exp.y:56:0:
```

gdb 10.1 compiled successfully before this.

I searched online but could not come up with a reason or solution.

What might be the issue ?

**Edit1:** I have `gcc version 7.5.0`

Comment: Could you include the commands you used to compile gdb, starting with the configure step (or whatever you started with)? I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62951784/72178 same problem but without solution.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21057 this GDB bug is probably related.

Comment: @rici I deleted the whole source folder, redownloaded it from the other source `sourceware.org`, and selected `tar.gz` instead of `tar.xz`, with the exact same version of gdb. I know it shouldn't make a difference but it compiled successfully this time.

Comment: @max: when I tried it, I used the tar.xz, and it seemed to work fine. I suspect that it's something environmental. I'm using flex 2.6.4, which apparently produces a slightly different scanner C file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced this issue and this is how I fixed it: 
`ada-exp.y` includes file `ada-lex.c` which contains the definition for function `lexer_init`. 
But if you don't have flex installed initially, then it may generate an empty `ada-lex.c` (from `ada-lex.l`). And even if you do `make clean`, it will not clean the generated `ada-lex.c`, i.e., it will remain empty upon next compile command as well. 
So to fix this error, you can delete all such intermediate `.c` files (in your case, building with fresh `.tar.gz`) and do the make again.